# Porting a C array to Python

Tags: python, c, arrays

I'm trying to port this `uint8` array to Python:

```
uint8 formatHwInfo[0x40 * 4] =
{
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x08,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x08,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x03,0x00,0x01,
    0x10,0x0B,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x03,0x00,0x01,
    0x10,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x03,0x00,0x00,
    0x20,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x03,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x0B,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x0B,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x0B,0x00,0x01,
    0x40,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x03,0x00,0x00,
    0x40,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x03,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x10,0x01,0x00,0x00,
    0x10,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x01,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x60,0x01,0x00,0x00,
    0x60,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x80,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x80,0x01,0x00,0x01,
    0x40,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x80,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00

};
 
uint32 surfaceGetBitsPerPixel(uint32 surfaceFormat)
{
    uint32 hwFormat = surfaceFormat & 0x3F;
    uint32 bpp = formatHwInfo[hwFormat * 4];
    return bpp;
}
```

What is the best way to represent it?

Comment: That's not a structure, that's an *array*. Now think back to your [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) days, what in Python behaves like an array? Something which can be indexed with a zero-based number? Perhaps you should go through [some parts of the tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator) again?

Comment: If you want to keep it contiguous, you may want to have a look at the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the array to a byte string:

```
formatHwInfo = b"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x03\x00\x01\x08\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x10\x07\x00\x00\x10\x03\x00\x01\x10\x03\x00\x01" \
    b"\x10\x0B\x00\x01\x10\x01\x00\x01\x10\x03\x00\x01\x10\x03\x00\x01" \
    b"\x10\x03\x00\x01\x20\x03\x00\x00\x20\x07\x00\x00\x20\x03\x00\x00" \
    b"\x20\x03\x00\x01\x20\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x03\x00\x00" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x20\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x20\x0B\x00\x01\x20\x0B\x00\x01\x20\x0B\x00\x01" \
    b"\x40\x05\x00\x00\x40\x03\x00\x00\x40\x03\x00\x00\x40\x03\x00\x00" \
    b"\x40\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03\x00\x00\x80\x03\x00\x00" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x10\x01\x00\x00" \
    b"\x10\x01\x00\x00\x20\x01\x00\x00\x20\x01\x00\x00\x20\x01\x00\x00" \
    b"\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x60\x01\x00\x00" \
    b"\x60\x01\x00\x00\x40\x01\x00\x01\x80\x01\x00\x01\x80\x01\x00\x01" \
    b"\x40\x01\x00\x01\x80\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" \
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

def surfaceGetBitsPerPixel(surfaceFormat):
    hwFormat = surfaceFormat & 0x3F
    return ord(formatHwInfo[hwFormat*4 + 0])
```

Comment: Cannot mix bytes and nonbytes literals.

Comment: @AboodXD: oh, yes, every line should contain bytes.

Comment: So, what shall I do now? Removing the "b" works, but that means it won't be bytes anymore, right?

Comment: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found